# Iron-Router Login and Register best practice

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I would be grateful for some feedback on my Iron-Router logged out redirection code.

I intend to only allow logged in users to access routes **other** than login or register and to redirect others to login with error code.

```
// routes.js with Router.beforeAction
if (!Meteor.userId()) {
  // Get current route
  var currentRoute = Router.current().route.getName();
    // if the current user is not trying to login or register send to login with error
  if (currentRoute = 'register'){
      this.layout('login');
      this.render('registerview');
    } else if (currentRoute = 'login') {
      this.layout('login');
      this.render('loginview');
    } else {
      Session.set("errorMessage", "You need to log in to access this page.");
      this.redirect('/login');
    }
} else {
    // otherwise don't hold up the rest of hooks or our route/action function
    // from running
    this.next();
}
```

This works but i would appreciate some feedback on efficiency and good code.

Also my routes.js file is in /client , I know that the login logic should be sent to server methods but is there any security concern for the route file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of logic, I could say that it is ok. But I would do it in another way:
 I usually do all the tests in the `onBeforeAction()` hook. I do the validations using functions and if all  validations pass, I call `this.next()`. If there is an error the router redirects (using `Router.go()`) to a route which an unregistered user could see. 
Concerning the folder, I place the `router. js` in the `root/lib` folder.
 Example :

```
Router.onBeforeAction(mustBeSignedIn, {only:  [the templates you want to check]});
```

Comment: So, the feedback then is: define the tests as functions and call them in this way. I am editing the answer, too.